# Git Diff between HEAD and SVN Master

Tags: svn, git, diff

I want to do a Diff between a locally commited change and between the SVN commited last change. i.e. HEAD and what is on SVN Master trunk.

what would be the suitable command?

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

I assume you're talking about git-svn:

```
$ git-svn fetch              # get the latest from svn, without merging yet
$ git diff ..remotes/git-svn # or <treeish>..remotes/git-svn
```

I don't know if `remotes/git-svn` can be somewhere else. Check with `git branch -a`.

Answer (score 6):

`git diff trunk` worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be making a diff between `HEAD` and the import of `trunk` into a git repo.

But if you cannot do a `git svn rebase` on your current repo because you do not want to import anything (but only see the difference with the SVN repo), you could clone your repo into a second repo where you can at any moment refresh its content with the SVN `trunk`.

Then you declare a tracking branch and fetch that repo2 in your current repo:

```
master/HEAD
svn_trunk    # tracks repo2/trunk/HEAD, refreshed by a git svn rebase
```

and you can diff:

```
git diff svn_trunk..HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

git diff HEAD~3 HEAD

and it worked as I wanted to see the diff between 3 locally committed changes and the HEAD on trunk.

But was it the right way? It worked though! :)

Comment: If you know that the last svn rebase was `HEAD~3`, then yes. It should be the same than `git diff HEAD~3..`